# How to disallow disabled users from logging in, into a page using passport.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, passport.js

I've used a soft delete feature in mongodB to disable a user and not delete it permanently. Now, only enabled users can log in to the site while the disabled users can not log in to the site.

```
// Soft delete feature

    exports.getDisabledUsers = function(req,res, next) {
        User.find({active: false}, function(err, users) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json(users);
        });
    }

    // Log In

    exports.login = function (req, res, next) {

        var userInfo = setUserInfo(req.user);

        res.status(200).json({
            token: 'JWT ' + generateToken(userInfo),
            user: userInfo
        });

    };

    // Passport.js

    var localLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, function (email, password, done) {

        User.findOne({
            email: email
        }, function (err, user) {

            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    error: 'Login failed. Please try again.'
                });
            }

            user.comparePassword(password, function (err, isMatch) {

                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }

                if (!isMatch) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        error: 'Login failed. Please try again.'
                    });
                }

                return done(null, user);

            });

        });

    });
```

Disabled users shouldn't be able to log in. Right now, they are able to log in.

Answer (score 1):

While Disabling the user you can move that data to another collection, that way your disabled user cannot be able to login to your system

```
exports.disableUser = function (req, res, next) {
       User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:req.params._id}, {active: false}, function (err, users) {
           if (err) {
               res.send(err);
           }
     User.findByIdAndRemove(
        {_id:req.params._id}, 
         function(err, doc) {
             if (doc) {
                 DisableUser.insertMany(doc, function(err, doc){
                  // your response
                 });
             } else {
               // your response
         }
     )
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not checked user status is active or not. This can be done by adding a condition in code, or modifying mongo query and adding one more condition in findOne.

//CODE

if(!user.active) {

//RETURN USER IS NOT ACTIVE

}

//MONGO QUERY

User.findOne({
            email: email,
            active: true
        }, function (err, user) {
//YOUR CODE
}

Answer (score -1):

Role based login may create some complexity but this can be achieved simply by adding one more collection named disabledUsers

when admin disable any user then the click function do two things at the same time 
1)add the email into disabledUser collection
2)delete the user from user collection

Then in your login function just check this way

```
disabledUser.findOne({email :email },
    function (err ,user){
       if(err) return done(err)
       else{
         if(!user){
           user.findOne({email : email }
           write your login stuff here the wau you r doing
           }
         else{return alert('user is disabled')}
       }
```

})